# Is there any possibility to capture CSP errors through Javascript

Tags: javascript, error-logging, content-security-policy

I have added Content-Security-Policy in my site header and I am trying to log Content-Security-Policy errors happening in client side using Javascript.

Can you please let me know any possibility to capture CSP errors through Javascript

Comment: On client side - **no way**. Otherwise [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Security_Policy#Reporting) might help

Answer (score 3):

A [SecurityPolicyViolationEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#securitypolicyviolationevent) DOM Event was added to [Content Security Policy Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/).  From the [Changes from Level 1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#changes-from-level-1) section:

> A [SecurityPolicyViolationEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#securitypolicyviolationevent) is fired upon violations, as
>   described in [§6.3 Firing Violation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP2/#firing-securitypolicyviolationevent-events).

However, browser support is limited (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2)

Comment: note, in 2022 support is okay

Answer (score 0):

Your headers can include a `report-uri`, which specifies an endpoint to report CSP violations to. You can collect these yourself or send them to a error reporting service like [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry).

```python
def middleware(request, response):
    response['Content-Security-Policy'] = \
        "default-src *; " \
        "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.example.com cdn.ravenjs.com; " \
        "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' cdn.example.com; " \
        "img-src * data:; " \
        "report-uri https://app.getsentry.com/api/54785/csp-report/?sentry_key=SENTRY_KEY"
    return response
```